# CKEDITOR plugin acf allow con

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, advanced-custom-fields

I'm creating a plugin in which I need to be able to add classes to spans. I've read the documentation on CKEditors website but it hasn't helped me. This is what I'm trying:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add( 'mymodule', {

    init: function( editor )
    {
        editor.path = this.path;
        editor.css = "styles.css";

        CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = "span(added,removed)";

        // other stuff
    }
}
```

These classes are added to the editor during an editor.on("change") event.

I don't want to just disable ACF because that's the cheap way out. I have gotten ACF to work for my dialog box, allowing a class to a custom tag. The classes for SPAN are not added through my dialog however so I think that's why doesn't work there.

```
var command_comment = editor.addCommand( 'comment', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('comment', {
    allowedContent: 'comment(comment)'
}) );
```

This however allows comment but not span classes:

```
var command_comment = editor.addCommand( 'comment', new CKEDITOR.dialogCommand('comment', {
    allowedContent: 'comment(comment); span(added)'
}) );
```

Comment: What HTML elements with what classes do you want to allow precisely? Because there's no `<comment>` element in HTML.

Comment: I figured it out a while ago, but I was trying to make my own <comment> tag.

Comment: For that you also need to extend the [`CKEDITOR.dtd`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd) object.